# Crear variables en masa Python

Tags: python

¿Existe alguna forma en Python de asignar valores a variables sin teclear especificamente el nombre de la variable? Me explico con un ejemplo, lo que me gustaría hacer es algo como:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for e in list:

     1 + "variable" = XXX
```

Y tener de output:

```
1variable = XXX

2variable = XXX

3variables = XXX
```

...

Creo que se entiende la cuestión. Soy novato y no tengo claros algunos conceptos. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: En python, los nombres de variables tienen que empezar por letra o el carácter de subrayado `'_'`. ¿Te daría igual que el número vaya al final del nombre?

Comment: ¿Y no te sería mucho más útil tener una lista llamada `variable`,  en lugar de una serie de variables llamadas `variable1`, `variable2`,...? En el fondo para eso son las listas. Puedes verlas como una serie de variables llamadas `variable[0]`, `variable[1]`, `variable[2]`... No sólo te será más fácil crearlas "en masa", sino también iterar por ellas para hacer cosas. `for i in range(5): variable[i]=XXX`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Chema. No era el objeto de lo que preguntaba pero gracias, ahora he aprendido que las variables no pueden empezar por un número (era un ejemplo no lo sabía).

Comment: Y gracias por la respuesta abulafia. Una lista es lo que tengo ahora. Un saludo.

Comment: @abulafia necesito aprender eso que dices. Acabo de crear una pregunta muy similar a esta. Me puedes ayudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para empezar, los nombres de variables no pueden comenzar con números, después, sugeriría mejor que utilizaras un diccionario para almacenar valores con claves de nombre variable, o un objeto, según la necesidad del proyecto.

Pero de todas maneras, respondiendo directamente a tu pregunta, una forma que se me ocurre es con la función `exec`, por ejemplo.

```
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...     exec "var%s = %s" % (i, i*i)
...
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...     exec "print var" + str(i)
...
1
4
9
16
25
...
```

Otra forma que se me ocurre es usando diccionario `globals`, que contiene las variables globales.

```
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...     globals()["var" + str(i)] = i*i
...
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...     print globals()["var" + str(i)]
...
1
4
9
16
25
...
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...     exec "print var" + str(i)
...
1
4
9
16
25
...
```

Para los objetos puedes usar algo de metaprogramación sencilla como:

```
>>> class Lista(object):
...     pass

>>> i = 1

>>> lista1 = Lista()
>>> for elemento in ["jitomates", "mantequilla", "huevos"]:
...     setattr(lista1, "producto" + str(i), elemento)
...     i = i + 1
...
>>> lista1.producto1
'jitomates'
>>> lista1.producto2
'mantequilla'
```

Aunque se pueden hacer toda clase de locuras, creo que es mejor que utilices diccionarios.

Comment: +1 Has respondido directamente a lo que el usuario preguntaba, mostrando algunas técnicas interesantes. Pero algo me dice que este era un caso de pregunta XY (preguntar por X cuando en realidad se necesita Y). Quizás lo que el usuario necesitaba era simplemente una lista. En ese sentido le he respondido en un comentario. Si quieres puedes ampliar la respuesta con esa posibilidad.

Comment: Buenas tardes y gracias por tu respuesta. He probado a hacerlo a través de exec y me han funcionado perfectamente. Aún así he seguido la recomendación y estoy almacenando los valores para la asignación en diccionarios. Muchas gracias.