# ¿se pueden crear variables de forma automatica en python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

la idea es así:

```
for i in range(2,4):
    hola+str(i)=i
Resultado:
hola2=2
hola3=3
hola4=4
```

y que sean variables que funcionen como si uno las hubiera declarado

Esto da el error **"cannot assign to operator"** pero mi duda es si técnicamente es posible algo asi? solo por curiosidad, soy nuevo en esto. gracias :)

Comment: A que te refieres con crear variables, un tipo de dato diferente a los que existen o que ?

Comment: @soyunewok me refiero a que si se pueden generar variables de forma "automatica"    quiero decir        objeto1=1 objeto2=2 objeto3=3 y asi sucesivamente dentro de un bucle

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Crear variables en masa Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/250979/crear-variables-en-masa-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con la aclaración que diste, pues si, normalmente lo que quieres se hace con un arrary o una estructura de datos, python maneja varias estructuras de datos como arrays, diccionarios y listas.

Entonces para empezar esto esta mal porque no estás haciendo una correcta asignación de un valor a una variable, sobre todo porque no estas definiendo bien la variable.

```
for i in range(2,4):
   hola+str(i)=i
```

Lo mas sencillo que puedes usar es una lista, que es parecido a un array para esto:

```
hola=list()
for i in range(2,4):
    hola.append(i)
```

Luego para imprimir:

```
for num in lista:
    print(num)
```

Esto te imprimria los números, desde el 2 hasta 4, en consecuencia tendrias:
hola[0]=2
hola[1]=3

Answer (score 2):

La función `exec` recibe como parámetro un string conteniendo código Python, el que es ejecutado como si fuera parte del código que lo llama. Por tanto

```
a = 1
exec("b=a+5")
```

es igual que

```
a = 1
b = a + 5
```

Notese que la expresión es calculada con el valor actual de "a", y el resultado es la creación de una nueva variable "b" con valor 6.

Lo que pides se obtiene asi:

```
for i in range(2, 5):
    exec("hola%d=i" % i)

print(hola2)
print(hola3)
print(hola4)
```

produce

```
2
3
4
```

Pero, como otros han dicho, lo apropiados es usar listas.